# Mocking verify DbSet failed with GetEnumerator unverified

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, moq

I'm trying to mock our database with moq right now.
Here I have the problem that some methods from the EntityFramework return DbSet objects which I iterate over in my code using foreach.

Now I call VerifyNoOtherCalls(); at the end of the defined test methods.But here the test blows up in my face, because the foreach loop calls GetEnumerator() from the IEnumerable Interface, which I don't verify. But this is not possible because the DbSet itself does not implement GetEnumerator() and moq does not allow to call a ToList() in the Lambda.

Now I have two questions:

1. How is it possible that DbSet implements the IEnumerable interface but does not implement the GetEnumerator method directly or in the base class?
2. how do I get the test running? I have already found several instructions on the internet, so I have decided to mock DbSet myself:

```
        public static DbSet<T> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
        {
            var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

            var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
            dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Add(s));

            return dbSet.Object;
        }
```

However, this does not work either.

Comment: I don't use EF, but if you're using a foreach, shouldn't you be mocking `dbSet.As<IEnumerable<T>>()` rather than `.As<IQueryable<T>>()` ?

Foreach will first cast to the appropriate 'IEnumerable' type if I remember well, so that's the interface that would need to be mocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question, [`DbSet<>` has an *explicit* implementation for `IQueryable.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#explicit-interface-implementations). This allows DbSets to be used as `IEnumerable<>`s without cluttering intellisense and such with methods that aren't typically called on the DbSet directly.

I'm not positive why the code you've posted isn't working, but you can try mocking the `GetEnumerator()` on `dbSet.AsIEnumerable<T>()`.

At a higher level, though, I've found there's little value in *mocking* the DbSet (treating it like a *service* whose methods you need to mock and verify). I would focus on *faking* it (treating it like a collection, whose contents you can specify). So calling `VerifyNoOtherCalls()` is probably not helpful, based on my experience.